# Is there any way to specify a block of code that should run at the start of every Airflow operator?

Tags: python, airflow, initializer

We have some setup code that we want to ensure will run at the start of every operator.

The best we can do right now is create a base operator that all other operators inherit from, and call the setup code from the pre-execute function for that operator. However, we have no way of enforcing that all future operators that developers write must inherit from that operator, so it's still possible for people to write operators that don't run the important setup code.

Is there a way to make a pre-execute function that is universal to all operators?

Answer (score 0):

I'd summarise you have 2 options to go forward. Option 1 is slightly more practical, technical, requires patch but has heaps of benefits. Option 2 is to extend your first suggestion practically.

---

### Option 1

Find the file source where the airflow BaseOperator is installed. Copy it and amend the file so that the definition of `pre_execute` method has your functionality. Use `diff` to generate a `diff` file that you can apply with `patch` file. Call if `OVERRIDE-apply-library-preexecute.diff`.

Then you need to load this diff file as part of your install or provisioning step. Install airflow as normal. Then you can use the `patch` tool. A command like `patch -d <PATH> -p1 < OVERRIDE-apply-library-preexecute.diff`

This has the least amount of code, will fail quite clearly (as things change), and you don't have to have unittests. And you're guaranteed every Operator will execute your pre_execute method.

---

### Option 2

I would suggest you're exactly looking in the right direction.

I'd recommend simply implementing your code as a Mixin, provide all operators in use in your own code, and use unittests to ensure that DAGs use Tasks that directly inherit that Mixin.

You might define your Mixin Class something along the lines of:

```py
import logging

from airflow.models import BaseOperator

class MyPreExecuteMixin(BaseOperator):
    def pre_execute(self, context):
        logging.info("Global Pre Execute")
```

This would force you to provide a version of each Operator you want to use inside your own library like so...

```py
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator as _DummyOperator
from mylibrary.models import MyPreExecuteMixin

class DummyOperator(_DummyOperator, MyPreExecuteMixin):
    pass
```

And then you'd have to have a test suite along the lines of...

```py
from dags.mydag import dag

def test_all_pre_execute():
    non_pre_execute_tasks = [task for task in dag.tasks if type(task) != MyPreExecuteMixin]
    assert not non_pre_execute_tasks
```

Comment: I see you could more expressly write your unittest as:
```
assert all([type(task) == MyPreExecuteMixin for task in dag.tasks])
```